# Read/Write plist

Tags: iphone, plist

I have some question about the reading/writing a plist.
I use this cose for read plist

```
NSString *strFilePath = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"miodb" ofType:@"plist" ] ;

NSMutableDictionary *dictMioDB = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strFilePath] ;

NSString *strValue ;
strValue = [dictMioDB objectForKey: @"stringa1" ] ;
NSLog( @"%@" , strValue ) ;
```

And for write plist I use this code:

```
NSString *strFilePath = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"miodb" ofType:@"plist" ] ;
NSLog( @"%@" , strFilePath ) ;

NSMutableDictionary *dictMioDB = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strFilePath] ;

NSString *strTextField = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@" , [txtField text] ] ;

// ga - salvataggio del valore nella chiave nel NSMutableDictionary
[dictMioDB setValue: strTextField forKey:@"stringa1"];
[dictMioDB writeToFile: strFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Now the problem is that the plist must be saved in Documents directory
So I used this code:

```
//percorso file su cartella documents
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iOre.sqlite"];
    //[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];

//controllo se il file esiste
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    //se non esiste lo copio nella cartella cosuments
    NSString *pathLocale=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iOre" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:pathLocale toPath:path error:nil] == YES) 
    {
        NSLog(@"copia eseguita");
    }
}
```

Now I have join the two pieces of codes in this:

```
  //percorso file su cartella documents
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LevelsD.plist"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];

NSString *pathLocale;

//controllo se il file esiste
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    //se non esiste lo copio nella cartella documents
    pathLocale=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LevelsD" ofType:@"plist"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:pathLocale toPath:path error:nil] == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"copia eseguita");
    }
}

// ga - trovo la posizione del .plist
//NSString *strFilePath = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LevelsD" ofType:@"plist" ] ;
NSLog( @"%@" ,documentsDir) ;

// ga - copio tutto il .plist (la root è un Dictionary) in un NSMutableDictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dictMioDB = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentsDir] ;

NSString * txtField = @"1";

//NSString *strTextField = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@" , txtField ] ;

// ga - salvataggio del valore nella chiave nel NSMutableDictionary
[dictMioDB setValue: txtField forKey:@"LevelHere1"];
[dictMioDB writeToFile: pathLocale atomically:YES];
```

This don't work but now I have some doubts. In my plist file I don't see any change but is possible that value of 'txtField' was saved into 'dictMioDB'? How I can see if a record/string was inserted into my plis? Another doubt: When I write something into Document folder with the simulator the data will be deleted when I close this or when I will re-compile the app? While in the Iphone this data will deleted when I remove the app? Right?
The last dubt: When I will read a plist that is in document folder I can use the firs code that search automatically the path of plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing file, you are doing wrong as you can not write file to main bundle. It must be written in documents directory:

```
+ (NSString *) getFilePathInDocsDir: (NSString *)fileName
{
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docsDir = documentPaths[0];
    NSString *filePathInDocsDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return filePathInDocsDir;
}
```

So use this function and write the file to returned path only, not in main bundle